# Accessible Links

Tags: jquery, accessibility, keyboard-events, wcag2.0

I have a few input elements inside a Bootstrap `panel-heading`. I've got click handlers on these which works fine using a mouse, but I need them to be keyboard operable for WCAG compliance. Is there an easy way to have them respond to click OR spacebar/enter press? The only way I can see are either:

- Changing the  tags to buttons and removing the button styling with CSS
- Adding a keydown trigger to the document and checking `e.keyCode`

Both of which seem long winded and kind if hackey.

**EDIT**: To be specific. In the header, I have the following structure:

```
------------------------------------------
- \/ Section Name      [15]       [On/Off]
------------------------------------------
```

Wrapping the elements in individual `<a>` tags allows them to receive focus, but only actually clicking the section name will trigger the expand handler.

Comment: Input elements can receive tab focus by default, which is usually sufficient to be considered accessible to keyboard-only users. Can you please explain what action you want to achieve with a "click OR spacebar/enter press?"

Comment: Detail added :)

Comment: I guess that I'm a little confused here. My understanding of Bootstrap panels is that they are static (and also deprecated in v4). What you're describing here seems to be more like a Bootstrap Accordion component. Is there some reason that you're not using one of those? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Comment: The accordion is pretty much what we have, but we use BS3 and upgrading to BS4 isn't planned until next year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by using `<button>` elements instead of anchors and spans and toggling the `aria-expanded` attribute via JavaScript.